# VBA to import and transpose multiple sheets data

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I have been working on the below code, however I am looking to edit this further:

1) Instead of setting 'Set Range1' via an input box, this should always be the cell range of 'B2:P65' when looping through the sheets in the folder.

2) When pasting the data I want this to fill starting at column B of the 'Database' tab in the workbook and then subsequently C, D, E etc.. for the rest of the workbooks in the folder loop.

```
Sub LoopFileUpload_base()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myfile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
Dim rowIndex As Integer

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

  myExtension = "*.xlsx"

  myfile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

  Do While myfile <> ""
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=myPath & myfile)

'CHANGE CODE BELOW HERE

xTitleId = "Range"
Set Range1 = Application.Selection
Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, Range1.Address, Type:=8)
Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
rowIndex = 0

For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
    Rng.Copy
    Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Columns.Count
Next

'CHANGE CODE ABOVE HERE

      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
      myfile = Dir
  Loop

  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following macro where you loop through *.xlsx* workbooks in a folder and iteratively copy cells in specified range to current sheet row by row. Then, after each workbook move to next column:

```
Sub TransposeWorkbooks()
    Dim strfile As String
    Dim sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    strfile = Dir("C:\Path\To\Workbooks\*.xlsx")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("A2").Activate

    Do While Len(strfile) > 0

        ' OPEN SOURCE WORKBOOK
        Set sourcewb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\To\Workbooks\" & strfile)

        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate                    ' MOVE TO NEXT COLUMN
        ActiveCell = strfile

        ' ITERATE THROUGH EACH CELL ACROSS RANGE
        j = 1
        For Each cell In sourcewb.Sheets(1).Range("B2:P65")
            ActiveCell.Offset(j, 0).Value = cell.Value      ' MOVE TO NEXT ROW
            j = j + 1
        Next cell

        ' CLOSE WORKBOOK
        sourcewb.Close False
        strfile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: many thanks for the above, this has worked perfectly. There is one small change however, I need to loop the files in a folder which is not the same folder as where the workbook is stored - when I change the file path in 'strfile = Dir("' this does not work.

Comment: It was the `Set sourcewb` line which pointed to current workbook's folder and not the 'C:\Path\To\Workbooks' defined in `strfile = Dir` line. See edit above. Please adjust as needed. And do accept answer if it helped and to confirm resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you got your task solved.  For future reference, please try the AddIn from the link below.  I think you will find so many uses for this tool.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm